# Как унифицировать выдачу Serializer'а для каждого метода в контроллере?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Пишу стажировочный проект, имеем такой сериалайзер:

```
class PhotopostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :content, :picture, :comments_count, :rating_count, :liked_by_current_user

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments do
    comments = []
    object.comments.each do |comment|
      comments << { id: comment.id, content: comment.content, user: { id: comment.user.id,
                                                                      first_name: comment.user.first_name,
                                                                      last_name: comment.user.last_name,
                                                                      image: comment.user.image } }
    end
    comments
  end

  def liked_by_current_user
    object.rating.pluck(:user_id).include?(instance_options[:current_user])
  end
end
```

В контроллере имеем методы index и show, в каждом из них нужно свое количество комментариев (в индексе только 3, в show - все.)

Пытался сделать несколько классов, наследовавшихся от класса выше, но выдавало ошибки
`` undefined method `model_name' for Photopost::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class ``(при указании сериалайзера в контроллере) или `superclass mismatch for class PhotopostShowSerializer`(при первом запросе к методу после удаления указания сериалайзера)

```
def index
  photoposts = Photopost.custom_order(params[:order_by], params[:order_type])
  render json: photoposts, current_user: api_user.id, status: :ok
end

def show
  photopost = Photopost.find(params[:id])
  if photopost.moderating?
    if photopost.user == api_user
      render json: { message: "Post with id #{params[:id]} on moderation" }
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
  else
    render json: photopost, status: :ok, current_user: @api_user.id
  end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render json: { message: "Post with id #{params[:id]} is not found" }, status: :not_found
end
```

Помогите, не знаю куда копать дальше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, хоть это и не оптимально, решилось все изменением с has_many на def и добавлением проверки:

```
def comments
  comments = []
  if instance_options[:template] == 'index'
    object.comments.last(3)
  else
    object.comments.all
  end.each do |comment|
...
```